# Brain.js GPU slow training

Tags: javascript, neural-network, brain.js

I'm trying to train a neural network with brain.js - but am wondering if my data is already too big?

Code:

```
await getDataSet(type);

  const listings  = await getFilteredListings(type);
  const normalizer = new Normalizer(listings);

  normalizer.setOutputProperties(['runningTime']);
  normalizer.normalize();

  const inputs = normalizer.getBinaryInputDataset();
  const outputs = normalizer.getBinaryOutputDataset();
  const metadata = normalizer.getDatasetMetaData();

  fs.writeFileSync(METADATA_FILE[type],JSON.stringify(metadata));

  const trainingData=[];
  for(let i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    trainingData.push({input:inputs[i],output:outputs[i]});
  }
  const options={
    hiddenLayers:[180,60],
  };

  const net = new NeuralNetworkGPU(
    options
  );

  net.train(trainingData,{
    iterations: 60000, // the maximum times to iterate the training data --> number greater than 0
    errorThresh: 0.001, // the acceptable error percentage from training data --> number between 0 and 1
    log:true,
  });
```

Tried with amazon GPU instance - but it is suuuper slow. Would take 100h to train.

Features:

```
export const featureColumns = [
  'location.lat', 'location.lon', 'locationFactor.score', 'constructionYear', 'squareMeter', 'grossReturn','floor',
  'pricePerSqm', 'privateOffer', 'foreClosure', 'rented', 'apartmentType', 'condition'];
```

As you can see I've 13 Features - and roughly 50k training data. 
Why is it taking so long? Decreasing units in hidden nets speeds up the training but then the net can not make sense of the data.

Comment: Why use a (shared) server, use your machine, or multiples machines in cluster.

Comment: Am also using mine - but unfortunately I just have a macbook here - where the CPU and GPU is also WAYY to slow. Would take roughly 100h. Is that normal?

Comment: 60.000 epochs is also quite a lot. So you can expect training to take a long time. You might try to optmize your data first? Or buy an expensive GPU card.